# Differences between Qlikview and SQL query results

Tags: mysql, database, qlikview

I have Qlikview installed on my pc and it takes the data from a database.

I want to write an sql query which would take the same data(for automatization).

The problem is that my sql query returns 30+k more records than Qlikview.

I believe, that Qlikview is adding more restrictions than I do in my sql code.

So is there a way to find out what limitations and filters Qlikview is applying when retrieving data, so I could copy these filters to my sql script?

Comment: I understand that qlikview excutes your sql code... Please share query command from mysql and also copy your load script from Qlikview.